# fullcalendar.js - deleting event on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am using the fullCalendar.js and the current problem is making i lose so much time on something that might be simple to whose understand javascript (more specific jquery) better than me.

The link of my example is at the bottom but my main concern is this part:

```
eventClick: function(event){
  $(".closon").click(function() {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
  });
},
```

I want to delete an event from the calendar with my close button and not on direct click of the event. I already tried using the `$element.click` outside of the eventClick trigger but it closed all the events on the calendar and the max i could reach was this poor situation, where the user need to click first on the calendar event and after on the 'X' to delete it.

http://jsfiddle.net/59RCB/49/

Comment: suggest you use `eventRender` callback to add your `X`. Then you have access to the calendar event which you can use in click handler.  http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Comment: @charlietfl You are right. I only could figure that out with the CodeGodie snippet. I'm only not sure why that worked.

Comment: because it is adding the click handler to each individual close button, and removing the click handler from event itself

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Remove the eventClick function and replace the eventAfterAllRender function with this:

```
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.append( "<span class='closeon'>X</span>" );
            element.find(".closeon").click(function() {
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @codegodie


I only have one more concern. How i could append an $element outside the element's parameter (in its parent for example)? Is this even possible?

Thanks again

Comment: This works, but if you still want the eventClick handler for editing an existing event, add a parameter, e, to the closeon click handler and call e.stopPropagation() inside it.

Comment: How did you guys get this working? `element` itself is an <a> tag, so I cannot position anything within to be clickable through this parent <a> tag...

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean. Have you changed the CSS to make your `a` a `display:block` element?  I updated the jsfiffle, try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/59RCB/204/

Comment: It works perfectly on the month view. but on weekview and dayview I cannot delete the event.. how can i fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @nextdoordoc append the button inside the content div: `element.find('.fc-content').append();`

Comment: This does not work in the most updated version of fullCalendar.

Comment: @Whitecat just landed on this too. I foud a solution. To get it working with most recent fullCalendar the span should be added as a child of .fc-content `element.find('.fc-content').append( "<span class='closeon'>X</span>" );`

Answer (score 12):

Above solution works perfectly on the month view, but if you are on weekview and dayview, this solution will not work as pointed out by nextdoordoc above.
Why?  In weekview their is div element with ".fc-bg" as css class which is overlay with 25% opacity which blocks click event.

Workarround:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) { 
       element.find(".fc-bg").css("pointer-events","none");
       element.append("<div style='position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px' ><button type='button' id='btnDeleteEvent' class='btn btn-block btn-primary btn-flat'>X</button></div>" );
       element.find("#btnDeleteEvent").click(function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
       });
```

Adding `pointer-events:none` allows click event propagation.
Note: This solution does not work in IE10 and older.

To work in IE10 you can directly append you delete button to `(".fc-bg")`

here is example:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) { 
   element.find(".fc-bg").append("<div style='position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px' ><button type='button' id='btnDeleteEvent' class='btn btn-block btn-primary btn-flat'>X</button></div>" );}
```

Hope to help someone

Answer (score 2):

The way i found:

```
//HTML Code to add the button

<div id='calendar'></div>
<button id='Delete'>Delete Events</button></p>
```

-

```
//Our Js data
{id: '1', resourceId: 'a' , start: '2015-10-16T10:52:07', end: '2015-10-16T21:00:00', url: 'https//www.google.com', title: 'How to delete Events'},
{id: '2', resourceId: 'b' , start: '2015-10-16T11:00:10', end: '2015-10-18T17:03:00', title : 'Can we delete multiple events ?'},
{id: '2', resourceId: 'c' , start: '2015-10-16T10:00:00', end: '2015-10-16T23:00:02', title : 'How ?'},
],

//Need to set our button
select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
        console.log(
        'select callback',
        start.format(),
        end.format(),
        resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
        );
        }
        });

        //Our button to delete Events
        $('#Delete').on('click', function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', 2); //Remove events with the id: 2
            });

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

This code may better help you. In this code remove icon display you whenever your mouse moving over event and whenever your mouse goes outside remove button will hide or removed.

```
eventMouseover:function(event,domEvent,view){

    var el=$(this);

    var layer='<div id="events-layer" class="fc-transparent"><span id="delbut'+event.id+'" class="btn btn-default trash btn-xs">Trash</span></div>';
    el.append(layer);

    el.find(".fc-bg").css("pointer-events","none");

    $("#delbut"+event.id).click(function(){
        calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
    });
},
eventMouseout:function(event){
    $("#events-layer").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this will works for Month ,Week ,Day views

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {

            if (view.name == 'listDay') {
                element.find(".fc-list-item-time").append("<span class='closeon'>X</span>");
            } else {
                element.find(".fc-content").prepend("<span class='closeon'>X</span>");
            }
            element.find(".closeon").on('click', function () {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
            });
```