# Deleting events on close button click in FullcalendarJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm trying to find out how to make a 'close' button on my events in my calendar then simply delete that event on click. I cant seem to find solid documentation anywhere on this.

There was a [good solution posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530076/fullcalendar-js-deleting-event-on-button-click) but it seems this no longer works with the latest version of FullcalendarJS.

I'm looking to essentially do the same thing. Create a small X or close button on each event then once clicked, the event is closed/deleted.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. What exactly did not work?

Comment: Both examples in the link I sent through from a previous solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: So you didn't try anything yourself, or try to debug and modify those solutions to work with the newer version? What _exactly_ about them didn't work? Post _your_ attempt here, and we can help you to fix it. Until then the question is not answerable - we don't know if you tried those attempts properly, you haven't said what went wrong ("didn't work" does not constitute enough information to fix _any_ problem in the world, in any subject - not just programming) and you don't appear to have made much effort to solve the problem yourself other than copy/pasting and then shrugging when it failed